# Put space between <input> fields

Tags: css

Here's the page I'm working on:

http://jackalopemedia.com/webdesign.html

As you can see, the form is squished together. No clue why that is. Tried adding line-height and wrapping the form around a div, but that did nothing but move the button a bit (which I do want, but I want it ALL to be laid out nicely).

Also, another weird thing – the submit button, on hoverover, doesn't change the font color to red... it seems to stay white, even though I've specifically put it in the CSS.

Any ideas? Here's what I'd like it to look like:

http://jackalopemedia.com/branding.html

That contactform PHP doesn't work though, and when I swapped out one that does, it messed up the styling.

Thanks!

Comment: You should learn web design before you sell yourself as the best.

Comment: Please include your code in your question! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: Why do you think that you are good at webdesign ? You have simply set up a Twitter Bootstrap, and even this one is broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add css style `margin-bottom` to your inputs.

And for you button, use a css like

```
.btn{
   background-color:#000;
   color:#fff;
}
.btn:hover{
   background-color:red;
   color:#fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

margin-bottom  - margin bottom creates a distance between your elements and the next element below. So lets say i have a margin-bottom:20px.between two text inputs . It means that the distance between the two text input :the one below and above should be 20px. Or you. I think in your case margin-bottom is the best to use